# Trimble Maps Rest API mapRoutes Post - is there a way to change the icons for each stop in the route?

Tags: json, trimble-maps

Im using trimble maps REST API to get an image of a map with a route on it. Im using their mapRoutes endpoint (http://pcmiler.alk.com/apis/rest/v1.0/service.svc/mapRoutes).

Im creating the request body to include a route with 3 stop locations, I want the first stop location to have the red outline circle, the second stop to have a blue outline circle (without a number in it) and the last stop to have a green outline circle. No matter what I adjust in the request body I cannot adjust these icons, there are options within a PinDrawer node but the colours and icons there are very limited. If I cant change the colours I would like to at least get rid of the number in the second stop if possible. Any help with this is greatly appreciated, trimble's documentation for this isnt super clear

Here is my request body:

```
{
  "Map": {
    "Viewport": {
      "Center": null,
      "ScreenCenter": null,
      "ZoomRadiusSpecified": false,
      "CornerA": null,
      "CornerB": null,
      "RegionSpecified": false
    },
    "ProjectionSpecified": false,
    "Style": 5,
    "StyleSpecified": true,
    "ImageOptionSpecified": false,
    "WidthSpecified": false,
    "HeightSpecified": false,
    "Drawers": [ 22, 17, 12, 26, 2, 21, 5, 13, 11, 8 ],
    "LegendDrawer": null,
    "GeometryDrawer": null,
    "PinCategories": null,
    "TrafficDrawer": null,
    "MapLayeringSpecified": false,
    "Language": null,
    "ImageSourceSpecified": false
  },
  "Routes": [
    {
      "DrawLeastCostSpecified": false,
      "RouteLegOptions": null,
      "StopLabelDrawer": 3,
      "StopLabelDrawerSpecified": true,
      "RouteId": null,
      "Stops": [
        {
          "Costs": null,
          "IsViaPointSpecified": true,
          "Address": null,
          "Coords": {
            "Lat": "41.881832",
            "Lon": "-87.623177"
          },
          "RegionSpecified": false,
          "Label": "null",
          "PlaceName": null
        },
        {
          "Costs": null,
          "IsViaPointSpecified": true,
          "Address": null,
          "Coords": {
            "Lat": "42.317432",
            "Lon": "-83.026772"
          },
          "Region": 4,
          "RegionSpecified": true,
          "Label": null,
          "PlaceName": null
        },
        {
          "Costs": null,
          "IsViaPointSpecified": false,
          "Address": null,
          "Coords": {
            "Lat": "28.538336",
            "Lon": "-81.379234"
          },
          "Region": 4,
          "RegionSpecified": true,
          "Label": null,
          "PlaceName": null
        }
      ],
      "Options": null,
      "FuelOptions": null
    }
  ]
}
```

here is the resulting image:
[image]